# Unable to read queue in basic multiprocessing program

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I don't understand why the Queue object remains empty when running this basic program:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q, a, b):
    q.put(a * b)
    return

q = Queue()
p = Process(target=f, args=(q,1,2))
p.start()
p.join()

q.qsize() # returns 0
```

Do you see what's wrong? It's as if the queue got empty after the process died.

Comment: Are you running on Windows? Take all of the top level code (starting with `q = Queue()`) and put it under an `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement, otherwise it will execute in the child process when it is created (on a non-forking operating system)

Comment: This works on my linux machine.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it under Windows and executing it in interpreter mode (in Spyder), not as a script. Why can't the python interpreter create sub-processes?

Comment: It can create subprocesses generally, just not `multiprocessing.Process`. In windows as new python interpreter is executed and the state of the parent is pickled and sent to the worker to initialize it. Pickle pickles data and references to the modules defining the data. When running from the interpreter, there is no file in the file system holding the code so pickle fails.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines for some of the details

Comment: Well, the doc is pretty unclear. It even seems that my way of handling the queue may cause a deadlock (explained in section "Joining processes that use queues") but I don't understand why, especially as I've tested a script in which I join all the processes before emptying the queue.

Comment: The primary problem is that it can't import your main script because there is no backing file. If it could it would reexecute everything not in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. Then you get to the other issues!

Comment: The script works fine when including it within a main. I haven't noticed the deadlock problem.